# How to attach several PDFs in email template in Odoo 8?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, email-attachments, odoo-8

There is a button in `account.invoice` form named *Send by email*. When you click on it, the wizard of `mail.compose.message` is opened with the `email_template_edi_invoice` template loaded as default. As this template has the field `report_template` set with `account_invoices`, when you send the email, the PDF report of the selected `account.invoice` is attached to the email and sent.

My purpose is to manage almost the same functionality from the tree view too. So, I added a button *Send by Email* to the *More* option of the tree view. This new option is working well, I can select several invoices, click on the new button, and send the emails (a email is sent for each invoice, each one with its PDF attachment).

But as I wrote above, this is not exactly what I want. I want to select only invoices with the same `partner_id` (this can be controlled easily with Python code in the function called from *Sent by Email* button in tree view). I need to send only one email, with as many PDFs attached as selected invoices there are.

> Example: I am in `account.invoice` tree view, and I select the account
>   invoices *SAL_2016_0001* and *SAL_2016_0002* (suppose they have the
>   same customer **X**). After this, I click on *More > Send by Email*
>   (the option I implemented), and the pop-up of `mail.compose.message`
>   is opened. Here, I click on *Send* button, and an unique email must be
>   sent to the customer **X**, with two attachments, the PDF reports of
>   *SAL_2016_0001* and *SAL_2016_0002*.

For the moment, I have done this (I only paste the function called from the *Send by Email* button I implemented in the tree view):

```
@api.multi
def action_invoice_sent_multi(self):
    """ Opens email.compose.message form with the rightly template loaded. """
    template = self.env.ref('account.email_template_edi_invoice', False)
    form_view = self.env.ref('mail.email_compose_message_wizard_form', False)
    ctx = self.env.context.copy()
    ctx.update({
        'default_model': 'account.invoice',
        'default_use_template': bool(template),
        'default_composition_mode': 'mass_mail',
        'default_template_id': template.id,
        'mark_invoice_as_sent': True,
    })
    return {
        'name': 'Send Mail',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'views': [(form_view.id, 'form'), ],
        'res_model': 'mail.compose.message',
        'context': ctx,
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'target': 'new',
    }
```

I am stuck with this, I do not know what could I do to reach my purpose. Can anyone help me here, please?